# How to select the second element with a certain class?

Tags: html, css

Let me start by saying that I am aware of `nth-child` and as far as I can tell this will not work in my situation.  Say I have the HTML below:

```
<div>
    <div class="myclass">test1</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="myclass">test2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="myclass">test3</div>
</div>
```

And I want to highlight the div that contains `test2`.  From what I understand using `.myclass:nth-child(2)` will not work because it is looking for the second child instance of `myclass` and all the instances I have are first child.  You can see this not working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8sAm/).

So my question is how can I select the second instance of `myclass` from the above example using only CSS3?  I can't use javascript/jquery.

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
div:nth-of-type(2) .myclass {
    background:pink !important;
}
```

or

```
div:nth-child(3) .myclass {
    background:pink !important;
}
```

Comment: I think this assumes too much about the structure of the DOM and the parentage of the `.myclass` elements to work in the real world.

Comment: Ok, but without knowing the author's intent and given the question asked and the limitation of no javascript, it answers the question.

Comment: It's a little more fragile that I would like, but it might be workable.

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-of-type(2) > .myclass{
    background-color:red;
}
```

A tiny bit more robust.

Answer (score 0):

To follow imjared's answer, you might want to change how you think about the DOM... from your original question, it sounds like you're trying to get the second instance of .myclass to change, but CSS can't really look globally for all instances before and after.

Instead, I would think of it like this:

```
<some containing Element, like body> div:nth-of-type(2) .myclass {
    color: red;
}
```

What you're really trying to select is the .myclass element in the *second section* of some containing element.  The code in your question only works if the .myclass elements are direct siblings, which they aren't.